# Apply loader on "Select All" functionality of SumoSelect library

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, sumoselect.js

I am using sumoselect.js for my dropdowns. and i also have loader implemented in my project with id "mainloader".

Now i want when user click on select all then loader should show i.e $('#mainloader').show() and when sumoselect has selected all options inside dropdown then loader should removed i.e `$('#mainloader').hide().`

But I am unable to implement this functionality. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asiIl.png)

in sumoselect.js i have tried by adding my loader like below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9VU9.png)

but loader is showing after it is selecting all options but i want it should show instant when clicked on select and it should be hidden when all options are selected.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.